# Error as I try to create a primary key on a field with type Long

Tags: mysql, sql

While trying to create a table using the following `SQL` :

```
CREATE TABLE person(id INTEGER,r_id LONG,p_name TEXT,p_age INTEGER,
                        p_address TEXT,p_mobile LONG,PRIMARY KEY(r_id));
```

I am getting an error :

```
Error Code: 1170
BLOB/TEXT column 'r_id' used in key specification without a key length
```

What error is it ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you might want to re-think your decision to store a person's age.  It changes over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably wanted `bigint` instead of `LONG` which is a long **text** data type.

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
   id INTEGER,
   r_id BIGINT,
   p_name TEXT,
   p_age INTEGER,
   p_address TEXT,
   p_mobile BIGINT,
   PRIMARY KEY(r_id)
);
```

See [MySQL data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/other-vendor-data-types.html)

Comment: What is the corresponding for `bigint` in java ? It is not `Long`. I tested it with an error

Comment: It should work with `long`. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html). What connector are you using?

Comment: yeah.okay. There was a mistake